# How to mock useRoute() in vue testing library

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-testing-library

I ran into a problem when running a component test that has a line inside it:
`const route = useRoute()`. I get an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')`. Here is the test:

```
describe('Tariff card', () => {
  const options = {
    props: {
      name: 'test',
      tariffId: 2,
      price: 3990,
      maxCompanies: 1,
      maxCampaigns: 5,
      tariffNum: 2,
      isFree: false,
      duration: 30,
    },
    global: {
      plugins: [createTestingPinia()],
    },
  }

  it('render tariff card', async () => {

    jest.mock('vue-router', () => ({
      useRoute: jest.fn(() => ({ path: '/' }))
    }))

    render(TariffCard, options)
  })
})
```